# Can I name this example as an Adapter design Pattern? If 'No', Is any other design Pattern I can name for the same scenario?

Tags: java, design-patterns

**Please help me in this.**

I created an interface with m1,m2 methods. Let say I want flexibility for the class who wish to override these methods, Let say, either they want to override m1, m2, both or none. So My objective is to find out name of respective design pattern.

**Can this example be a name of any design pattern?** e.g Adapter etc.?

Interface

```
public interface AInterface {

    public void m1();

    public void m2();
}
```

abstract class

```
public abstract class AAbstract implements AInterface {

    public void m1() {  }

    public void m2() {  }

}
```

main

```
public class Main extends AAbstract {

    @Override
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("I am m1");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.m1();

    }
}
```

*Thanks in advance!!*

Comment: I wouldn't call it a design pattern. It's just some kind of default implementation of an interface that you can inherit from.

Comment: "*Help me to just give a name of design pattern if ANY!*" - Why? Besides, this might be better suited at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or  [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). This is not really any desing pattern. It is more of an anti-pattern since you have an abstract class with implemented, but empty methods. And even if you set the methods abstract, there is no reason to use the abstract class as middle layer. You could just directly implement the interface.

Comment: Definitely not an adapter.

Comment: Turing85, edited, thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Nico, Kayaman okay :)

Comment: If you want to provide flexibility to the consumer, you would be better to separate the methods into separate interfaces so the consumer can decide on exactly which methods to implement. This is the essence of interface segregation and is one of the SOLID principles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle

Comment: You may be interested in the [Decorator Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/decorator_pattern.htm).

Comment: It is not a design pattern. To give the client the flexibility you want you need to provide default implementation of `m1` and `m2`. You can do it with an abstract class or better have [default mehods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) with in the interface class.

Comment: It is not a design pattern. Actually it is not even compatible with SOLID. You should revise your design. If a class can not implement a method of an interface, it should not implement it. So you should revise the interface design.